# Right padding on a SQL Server varchar data via ADO .Net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, padding, varchar

I am developing a C# application in my company.
The application uses a SQL Server database via ADO .Net.
The application uses the ADO .Net data provider for SQL Server shipped with the .Net framework 4.

We are facing a problem when inserting a string programmatically into a varchar field.

## Example

Let's consider the database table named MY_TABLE with the following columns :

- MY_FIRST_COL int
- MY_SECOND_COL varchar(250)

I insert a record (REC1) into MY_TABLE by executing the following SQL query within SS Management Studio :

```
insert into MY_TABLE (1, "");
```

Then I select REC1 by using SSMS.
Then I copy the string contained in MY_SECOND_COL field.
Then I paste the string into Notepad++.
I notice the string is made up of 0 characters.
OK it makes sense !

Now I insert programmatically a record (REC2) into MY_TABLE by using an SqlCommand object.

Here is the string contained in the CommandText property :

```
insert into MY_TABLE (@p0, @p1);
```

Here are some values contained in properties of the SqlParameter object corresponding to the second parameter :

- DbType : System.Data.DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength
- Direction : Input
- IsNullable : false
- ParameterName : "@p1"
- Precision : 0
- Scale : 0
- Size : 0
- SqlDbType : Char
- Value : ""

Then I select REC2 by using SSMS.
Then I copy the string contained in MY_SECOND_COL field.
Then I paste the string into Notepad++.
I notice the string is made up of 250 characters.
Why ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlDbType : Char
```

That's your problem. You want `VarChar`. `Char`s are fixed width strings, padded with spaces.

[`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx):

> **Char**  [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) . A fixed-length stream of non-Unicode characters ranging between 1 and 8,000 characters.
>
> **VarChar**   [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) . A variable-length stream of non-Unicode characters ranging between 1 and 8,000 characters. Use **VarChar** when the database column is **varchar(max)**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SQL Data Type `char`.  Chars allocate the full space (250 characters in this case) where `VARCHAR` allocates only the needed space.

```
DECLARE @Result1 VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Result2 CHAR(200)

SET @Result1 = 'Hello' -- allocates 5 character spaces
SET @Result2 = 'Hello' -- allocates 200 character spaces

SELECT DATALENGTH(@Result1) -- 5
SELECT DATALENGTH(@Result2) -- 200
```